# How to manage SDK path in android studio while working with git from windows (one member) and ubuntu (other member)?

Tags: android

How to manage SDK path in android studio while working with git from windows (one member) and ubuntu (other member)?

Comment: AFAIK there is no need to micromanage this, ever. There is a file on every project that the IDE generates with the SDK path, are you committing this file to the repo? May be the source of your problem. Please provide more details if possible.

Comment: @IgorFilippov Questions about tools primarily used for programming are on topic, last time I checked both git and Android Studio are tools primarly used for programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio stores SDK path in `local.properties` file inside each of your projects root folder.

This file **must not be committed** to Git (or any other VCS) because it stores local settings that may differ from one developer to another.